# How to reopen breakpoint and variables window in Eclipse debug mode once windows are closed

Tags: eclipse

How can I reopen the breakpoint and variables window in Eclipse debug mode once the windows are closed?

After setting breakpoints in the code, when I click on

open perspective...>debug...>

initially I used to have breakpoint and variables window view

I closed them once and when I try to run the program in debug mode I'm not able to view them any more.

How can I get them back?

I'm using Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the debug perspective, and do

menu bar -> window -> show view

Comment: thx a ton for the quick response :)that really really did helped